# Auto Email google sheet response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help with a google app script to trigger an auto email to applicants that failed the quiz - scoring lower than 130 on column A on google sheets?

Thanks in advance for the help!

[Quiz Results Response](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JDjIkIC-vZ2dPbklIdz4VsboCyorpwZpToXDIgZ5t4k/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the mail to go automatically as soon as the form is filled? In that case, you can use the onFormSubmit trigger to send the mail to him automatically.

If you are processing the answers and then creating the result sheet, you can send the mail from the result sheet by processing each row in the sheet. You can easily find many examples how to send a mail from a sheet based on value in a column.

I am enclosing a similar code which sends the response to a user automatically as soon as he submits a form. I am storing his email ID (based on employee number) and sending him some data (based on his employee number) as soon as requests it. It works as a "employee self help portal".

```
function onFormSumbit(e) {
  var emp = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).getValue();
  var lvss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx"); // blanks https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kjOjhH0dvz4j3FsB_1UR5astpy8-ZxszNI4BZo4XJP0/edit#gid=0
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(lvss);
  var lvsht = lvss.getSheetByName("Blanks");
  var lvlr = lvsht.getLastRow();
  var vA =lvsht.getRange("A:L").getValues();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  html+='<tr>';
  for(var i=0;i< 4 ;i++) {//make title
       html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>',vA[0][i]);
     }
  html+='</tr>';
  for (i=1;i<lvlr;i++){
    if (vA[i][0]==emp){
      html+='<tr>';
      for (j=0;j<4;j++) {
         if ( j==2 ){
            vA[i][j]=Utilities.formatDate(vA[i][j],"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy");
          }//if date
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',vA[i][j]);
      }//for emp
      html+='</tr>';
    }//if
  }//for
  html+='</table><br>';
  var empss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx"); // emp master 
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(empss);
  var empsht = empss.getSheetByName("Emp");
  var emplr = empsht.getLastRow();
  var empvals =empsht.getRange("A:H").getValues();
  for (i=1;i<emplr;i++){
    if (empvals[i][0]==emp){
      var em1=empvals[i][7];
      var name=empvals[i][1]
      break;
    }//if
  }//for
  var subject="Your punch blanks "+name;
  if (em1=="") {} else {
  //MailApp.sendEmail(em1, subject, html);}
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: em1,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: html
    });
  }
}
//
//
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

This function processes the full spreadsheet data from first row to last row and sends failure notification emails where the score is less than 130 ...

```
function notifyFailedCandidates () 
{
  //Get the active sheet from the current spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Get all the rows from the spreadsheet
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow-1, lastColumn);
  var rows = searchRange.getValues();

  //loop through each of the rows
  for (var rowNumber in rows)
  {
    //Get each of the values from the row
    var quizScore = rows[rowNumber][0];
    var firstName = rows[rowNumber][1];
    var lastName = rows[rowNumber][2];
    var email = rows[rowNumber][3];

    //Send a failure notification if the score is less than 130
    if (parseInt (quizScore) < 130)
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail
      (
        email, //candidate email address
        'Notification of test failure', //Subject of failure notification email

        //Contents of failure notification email
        'Hi ' + firstName + "\n\n" + 
        'This email is to let you know that unfortunately you failed the test, with a score of ' + quizScore + ' / 170' + "\n\n" +
        'Better luck next time'
      );
    }
  }
}
```